# Multitask in GulpJS

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, gulp

How are you guys?

How do I create tasks in GulpJS similar to those that create in GruntJS?
Is possible?

Example:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    "use strict"

    grunt.initConfig({

        uglify: {
            options: {
                manage: false
            },
            dev: {...},
            prod: {...}
        },

        less: {
            options: {
                cleancss: true
            },
            dev: {...},
            prod: {...}
        }

    });

    grunt.registerTask("dev", ["uglify:dev", "less:dev"]);
    grunt.registerTask("prod", ["less:prod", "less:prod"]);
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is, how to run tasks in a series. Here is how you would do that:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

// takes in a callback so the engine knows when it'll be done
gulp.task('one', function(cb) {
    // do stuff -- async or otherwise
    cb(err); // if err is not null and not undefined, the orchestration will stop, and 'two' will not run
});

// identifies a dependent task must be complete before this one begins
gulp.task('two', ['one'], function() {
    // task 'one' is done now
});

gulp.task('default', ['one', 'two']);
// alternatively: gulp.task('default', ['two']);
```

You can read more about it here: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/running-tasks-in-series.md

Comment: No, I really want run separate tasks, but with tasks inside another. I know that is strange, but is it. :S

Comment: create one task for each combination, also use function for providing common options